# Need help copy paste loop

Tags: excel, python-2.7

I figured how to copy worksheet from one excel and past into another excel file tabs/worksheets. However I have about 50 excels (A.xlsx, B.xlsx.....) with only one tab/worksheet. And I want to paste the data from each file sheet into master file tabs (A.xlsx > MS1, B.xlsx > Ms2...../ where MS1 and MS2 are tabs of M.xlsx.

Also how write below code if the files are in .CSV format

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb1 = load_workbook('A.xlsx')
wb2 = load_workbook('M.xlsx')
sheet1 = wb1['AS']
sheet2 = wb2['MS1']

for i in range (1, sheet1.max_row+1):
    for j in range ( 1, sheet1.max_column+1):
        sheet2.cell(row=i,column=j).value = sheet1.cell(row =  i, column = j).value
 wb2.save('M.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

i use C# and Excel interop, so my answer might be short of what you need, but it might nudge you in the right direction.

I'd get a directory object, and loop through the directory.

Depending on the library you're using there might be a worksheet function that allows you to specify a worksheet to copy to.

So you'd have something like:

```
Workbook Masterbook;
Worksheet masterSheet = masterbook.sheets(1);
DirectoryInfo DirInf = new DirectoryInfo([DirectoryPath])

foreach (var wb in DirInf.GetFiles())
{
Wb.open
Worksheet sht = wb.Sheets(1)
sht.copy(before: masterSheet)
wb.close()
}
```